# How get get dynamically generated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

The following contain dynamic values

```
<c:forEach items="${allUserList}" var="eachUser">
        <span class="name"> ${eachUser.getUserName()} <span>
        <select class="role">
            <c:forEach items="${roleList}" var="eachRole">
                <option value="${eachRole.getRoleName()}">${eachRole.getRoleName()}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="add" />
    </c:forEach>
```

When i click on add button i should see corresponding name, selected role in a alert box `(e.g {jack, admin})`

How to do this??

Comment: Element IDs must be unique, so putting them inside a forEach doesn't make sense

Comment: lets assume its class, what then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the class attribute of the button as a selector, you can use the [.prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function to find the `<select>` element preceding the button:

```
$(".add").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).prev(".role").val()); // Role
    alert($(this).prevAll(".name").text()); // Name
});
```

You don't need event delegation in this instance, as JSP will generate this code before it reaches the client.

Comment: yes the role is showing. I also need the name as well. i tried alert($(this).prev(".name").val());  but its not working

Comment: Updated answer to print name & value

Comment: Updated to include search for name